# CKEditor sourcedialog get html data

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am struggling to get the HTML data from the sourcedialog in ckeditor.

I can get the HTML data from the editor itself, no problem. But getting it from the dialog is a pain in the ass.

I want to display a live preview of the HTML entered in the source dialog, and for that I need the HTML data, not from the editor, but from the dialog which the user is editing.

```js
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
  var editor = ev.editor;
  var dialog = ev.data.definition.dialog;
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
  var editorName = ev.editor.name;
  var htmlData = CKEDITOR.instances[editorName].getData();

  if (dialogName == 'sourcedialog') {
    dialog.on('show', function () {
      //console.log(this.getSize().width);
      console.log(this);
      $("#sourcePreview").css("display", "block");
      $("#sourcePreview").html(htmlData);

      $(".cke_dialog_ui_input_textarea textarea").on("keyup", function() {
        //var dialogElementUpdated = dialogObj.getElement().getFirst();
        //console.log(editorData);
        //$("#sourcePreview").html(htmlDataUpdated);
      });
    });
    dialog.on('hide', function () {
      console.log('dialog ' + dialogName + ' closed.');
      $("#sourcePreview").css("display", "none");
    });
  }
});
```

This is what I have so far (sorry about all the console.logs, this is work in progress). I am obviously getting HTML data from the varible: htmlData, but this is from the editor, not the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is great but yeah, there's a lot about it that's a pain in the ass.

```
if (dialogName == 'sourcedialog') 
{
  dialog.on('show', function () 
  {
    // 'input' is the correct event to listen to for a textarea,
    // it fires on paste too.
    this.getContentElement('main', 'data').getInputElement().on('input', function()
    {
      console.log('textarea contents: ' + this.$.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could provide a belated answer.  I happened to be wrestling with CKEditor and sourcedialog in a similar manner as you were and came across your question. If my answer (correctly) addresses your question please click the checkmark next to it.  Thanks!